# leaflet map resize areaselect based on two point coordinates

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using leaflet map. 
I'm using selecArea. By default when the map is loaded it is `width:200, height:300` , but I want to define it by two point coordinates: NE corner and SW corner.

```
var map = new L.Map('map', {
    selectArea: true
});

map.setView([14.378300, 24.904200], 5);

var tileLayer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 17,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
});
tileLayer.addTo(map);

var areaSelect = L.areaSelect({width:200, height:300});
areaSelect.addTo(map);
```

I have four input box where two point coordinates: NE corner(lat and long) and SW corner(lat and long). There's also a submit button.

On click, I get values from those fields and I want to resize the `areaselect` based on those.

I don't know how to resize the `areaselect` based on geographical coordinates

I thought that I can do like this,so I generated and rectangle and its bounds I want to pass to the `areaselect`:

```
 $( ".btn-resize-areaselect-by-points" ).click(function() {
            var neLatCoord = $('#ne-lat-coordinate').val();
            var neLonCoord = $('#ne-lon-coordinate').val();
            var swLatCoord = $('#sw-lat-coordinate').val();
            var swLonCoord = $('#sw-lon-coordinate').val();
            var bounds =  L.rectangle([  [neLatCoord, neLonCoord], [swLatCoord, swLonCoord]]);
            areaSelect.remove();
            areaSelect = L.areaSelect(bounds);
            areaSelect.addTo(map);
    });
```

But like that, it isn't working? Can someone help, how to resize areaselect based on two point coordinates: NE corner and SW corner?

Comment: @IvanSanchez is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure thats possible ! Regarding to the docs of [leaflet-areaselect](https://github.com/heyman/leaflet-areaselect) the arguments on an `L.areaSelect` object instance have to by in Pixel. What you are doing is to retrieve the bounds of the rectange in geographical Coordinates and then you try to initialize the `L.areaSelect` object with that coordinates. But that won't work ! So first you have to convert your geographical Coordinates to Pixel units and than pass it to your `L.areaSelect object`. Converting geogr. coords in leaflet from a point is done with the map method [`latLngToLayerPoint()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-latlngtolayerpoint).

In this example it could look like:

```
var width = map.latLngToLayerPoint(bounds.getBounds().getNorthEast()).x- map.latLngToLayerPoint(bounds.getBounds().getSouthWest()).x    
var height = map.latLngToLayerPoint(bounds.getBounds().getNorthEast()).y- map.latLngToLayerPoint(bounds.getBounds().getSouthWest()).y

var areaSelect = L.areaSelect({width:width, height:height });
```

It's the same like in your other [question post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118977/get-rectangle-width-and-height-leaflet-jquery/40126900#40126900).