# Get rectangle width and height leaflet jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dictionary, leaflet

I have a map and an area select field:

```
// initialize map
var map = L.map('map').setView([38, 0], 2);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/70146506bc514228adc1756788c730d3/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery &copy; <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>', maxZoom: 18}).addTo(map);

var areaSelect = L.areaSelect({
    width:100, 
    height:150, 
    keepAspectRatio:true
});
areaSelect.addTo(map);
areaSelect.setDimensions({width: 50, height: 50});
```

want to get the rectangle width and height.

```
var neLatCoord = $('#ne-lat-coordinate').val();
        var neLonCoord = $('#ne-lon-coordinate').val();
        var swLatCoord = $('#sw-lat-coordinate').val();
        var swLonCoord = $('#sw-lon-coordinate').val();
        var rectangle =  L.rectangle([  [neLatCoord, neLonCoord], [swLatCoord, swLonCoord]]).addTo(map);
```

So now I want to get the rectangle width and height so I can set dimensions  of the area select like this :

```
var rectangleWidth = rectangle.getBounds().getEast() - rectangle.getBounds().getWest();
var rectangleHeight = rectangle.getBounds().getNorth() - rectangle.getBounds().getSouth();
areaSelect.setDimensions({width: rectangleWidth, height: rectangleHeight});
```

but this gives another width and height? I don't know why?

Can someone help me please, cause I'm stuck on this?

Here's my [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3N2DN/74/#&togetherjs=Tmxt9h1aCL)

EDIT:

If I use rectangle instead of area select:

```
var rectangle = L.rectangle([  [21.616579,  29.487305], [7.798079, 20.522461]]);
map.addLayer(rectangle);

rectangle.editing.enable();

// Every time we move the selected rectangle, refresh data about the selected area.
rectangle.on('edit', function() { 

    selectedBounds = this.getBounds();
    console.log("Area:", selectedBounds);
    //some other code
});

$( ".select" ).click(function() {
    rectangle.editing.disable();    
    map.removeLayer(rectangle);
    rectangle =  new L.rectangle([  [17.853290, 34.980469], [10.876465, 14.853516]]);
    map.addLayer(rectangle);
    rectangle.editing.enable();
});
```

When I do this reset on clicking, the event `rectangle.on('edit', function() { ...` is not working? I don't know why? Can you help me, please

Answer (score 3):

Like the [docs](https://github.com/heyman/leaflet-areaselect) in leaflet-areaselect state, the method `.setDimensions()` needs arguments as Pixel and you give the arguments in geographical coordinates. With the [leaflet map method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-latlngtolayerpoint) `.latLngToLayerPoint()`  you are able to convert geogr. coords to Pixel of your map extend.

Just change

```
var rectangleWidth = rectangle.getBounds().getEast() - rectangle.getBounds().getWest();
var rectangleHeight = rectangle.getBounds().getNorth() - rectangle.getBounds().getSouth();
```

into

```
  var rectangleWidth = map.latLngToLayerPoint(rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast()).x- map.latLngToLayerPoint(rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest()).x    
  var rectangleHeight = map.latLngToLayerPoint(rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast()).y- map.latLngToLayerPoint(rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest()).y
```

Here is the working [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3N2DN/79/)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, but why the position of the select area is not the same as a rectangle?

Comment: Thats because areaSelect will allways be instantiated in the middle of the map canvas. But i edited my answer and created a new fiddle and now the ractangle is in the middle on the areaSelect.

If the answer is helpful, upvoting and accepting it would be a pleasure :)

Comment: I did an upvote. Please, I edited my question, can you check if you help me why I am having that problem?

Comment: Thats not a good practice to edit your answer and ask a new question in the same post ! If my answer was helpful to your old question accept it by clicking on the grey hook unter the voting and ask in a new question post !

Comment: Take a look on the fiddle and my eplanation. That answers all your question before you did the edit ! Now you need to open a new post and i am going to answer it !

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is about a year old, but I figured someone else might benefit from my trouble with the provided answer.

Leaflet actually provides 2 conversion methods:

- latLngToLayerPoint()
- latLngToContainerPoint()

The difference between the two has to do with how x,y positions are calculated.

**LayerPoint** finds x,y positions relative the top-left corner of the map *when it is initialized!!!* (Zooming resets this origin point, but panning does not!)

**ContainerPoint** finds x,y positions relative to the top-left corner of *the map container itself*.

Why does that matter?

If you initialize your map, pan it, and then get x,y coords using **latLngToLayerPoint()**, you can potentially get negative x/y values, which can lead to negative widths/heights if you don't actively compensate for them.

At least in my use-case, it was better to use **latLngToContainerPoint()** when determining boundary heights/widths in pixels.

Other than that, the above answer worked perfectly for me! :D